# SSL Certificate unexpectedley available in new Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I created a new Function App with a new App Service Plan in order to do a new release of some Functions I have.

In my old App Service Plan (non-Consumption) the certificate I had been using stopped functioning as my code stopped being able to retrieve it from the certificate store any more and I never identified the root cause.

Part of setting up a new App Service was to allow me to rectify this issue, but I was surprised to find the SSL certificate from the old App Service Plan was already present in this new App Service Plan and that it appears to work as expected (i.e. I can now read the cert in the Function code).

Is this expected behaviour? Same subscription and region but a different App Service Plan. I would not have expected a previously uploaded SSL certificate from another App Service Plan / Function App to be available to a new, unrelated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificates are scoped at subscription levels and not at App Service Plan level. In addition, the support for certificates in Consumption Function apps was recently enabled, which explains why you see it in there.

As an aside, to see that your certificates are Subscription level:

- Go to https://resources.azure.com/
- Go to your subscription
- Under it, go to `providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates`